# How do you return the array of markers created in Google Maps using a fusion table query?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Here's what I have and it shows the markers on the map, but I need the actual marker locations returned by the query. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
function queryFusionTable(lat, lng, radius) {

  var spatialCondition = "ST_INTERSECTS(location, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + lat + ", " + lng + ")," + radius + ")) "; 

  layer.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: 'location',
        from: tableid,
        where:  spatialCondition
      },
     });

 }
```

Comment: What does your table look like?  What type of date is in the 'location' column?  What have you tried? Have you done any research? Have you looked at any of the examples on http://www.geocodezip.com?

Comment: BTW - the answer to the question is "you can't", but you can query the fusion table separately for the locations (as long as they are coordinates, not geocoded addresses)