# Create links to map markers in map created with Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

A map is being created [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/uxcyjjvq/) (also see code at end of post).

What I'm trying to create is a list of links which would point to the markers on the map, in order to recenter the map and display infowindows when the links are followed.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957557/how-do-you-return-the-array-of-markers-created-in-google-maps-using-a-fusion-tab) makes it look as though an array of markers can't be retrieved when the map is created this way, so how else could I make a list of links?

```
    function initialize() {
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
  (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
if (isMobile) {
  var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
}
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '100%';
mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '500px';
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.81916145578315, -83.53575989454339),
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col18",
    from: "1P-2dj7mmKzaTY_cB8IS0nqL3Ou7_jOq5nuiL5QfN",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});

if (isMobile) {
  var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
  var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
  var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
  legend.style.display = 'none';
  legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
  legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
  legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
    legend.style.display = 'block';
    legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
  }
  legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
    legend.style.display = 'none';
    legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
 }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FusionTables map with clickable sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

Uses the google visualization API to query the table for the sidebar (limits the number of entries to a few hundred)

```
function  createSidebar() {

  //set the query using the parameter
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'Name', 'Lat', 'Focus Area', 'Contact', 'Contact alt' FROM "+FT_TableID);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);


  //set the callback function
  query.send(getData);

}

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(createSidebar);

 var FTresponse = null;
//define callback function, this is called when the results are returned
function getData(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

  //concatenate the results into a string, you can build a table here
  fusiontabledata = "<table><tr>";
    fusiontabledata += "<th>" + response.getDataTable().getColumnLabel(0) + "</th>";
  fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";

  for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      fusiontabledata += "<td><a href='javascript:myFTclick("+i+")'>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0) + "</a></td>";
    fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  fusiontabledata += "</table>"  
  //display the results on the page
  document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxcyjjvq/2/)  (the infowindow from the sidebar is not the same as the native one)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough answer and knowing what I was looking for; I didn't think to use the term 'FusionTables map with clickable sidebar.'